# React map get request data but ignore empty fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, get, axios

Basically i'm trying to map through a API get response, collect the data i need and send it to set state so i can feed the data into a google bar chart.

The API is list of Nasa NEO's and i need their name, min and max size and what planet they orbit.

I managed to do the first 3 but i can't work out how to get the last part because of the 20 NEO's only half of them have what planet they orbit in the data.

So how can i put a condition in the loop telling it to return null or something else instead of undefined seeing as google charts needs a value on all of them.

```
 state = {
    data: [
             ['name', 'min estimated diameter', 'max estimated diameter', "fdsf"],
    ],
}

componentDidMount() {
axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse?api_key=DEMO_KEY',)
.then((response) => { // destructure data from response object
    // {name, estimated_diameter} from data
    const planet = response.data.near_earth_objects.close_approach_data
    console.log(planet)
    console.log(response)
    const restructuredData = response.data.near_earth_objects.map(({name, estimated_diameter, close_approach_data }) => 
        [name, estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_min, estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_max, close_approach_data[0]])
    const joined = this.state.data.concat(restructuredData)
    this.setState({data: joined});
})
```

Comment: How your API response looks like? Can you elaborate on that more a bit? Thanks!

Comment: Basically it gives you a list of 20 NEO's all 20 have a name and min/max sizes but on half of them the close_approach_data array is just a empty array. So when i use map to get close_approach_data it returns undefined on half of them.

Comment: Is this a duplicated question to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59695738/how-to-map-through-api-data-when-each-data-array-is-different/59695900#59695900, if that's the case please check my ans there to see if it helps