# how to map through API data when each data array is different

Tags: reactjs, get, axios

I'm trying to map through this API: https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse?api_key=DEMO_KEY

and feed data into my state so I can make a google chart, but I'm stuck on how to do a certain part.

At the moment I have this.

```
state = {
    data: [
             ['name', 'min estimated diameter', 'max estimated diameter'],
    ],
}
```

then when the page runs my CoponentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount() {
axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse?api_key=DEMO_KEY',)
.then((response) => { 

    const restructuredData = response.data.near_earth_objects.map(({name, estimated_diameter,}) => 
        [name, estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_min, estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_max]
    )

    const joined = this.state.data.concat(restructuredData)
    this.setState({data: joined});
})
```

this should take the data from the API create an object with the name, `minSize` and `maxSize` then add it under my current data state.

All this currently works fine.

The problem is that I also need the planet it orbits around.

[this is data schematic for API I retrieve](https://api.nasa.gov/neo/?api_key=DEMO_KEY#!/rest%2Fv1%2Fneo/browseNearEarthObjects)

So here is my main problem in close_approach_data : []

I need to retrieve orbiting_body but when I request data from the API only about 10 of the 20 objects have a close_approach_data object with anything in them, the other half is empty.

so google charts won't run because I end up with undefined in the half my objects.

So what can I do to fix it or make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

close_approach_data is an array of objects. It seems like it's always present to me, and the following works:

```
axios
  .get('https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse?api_key=DEMO_KEY')
  .then((response) => {
    const restructuredData = response.data.near_earth_objects.map(
      ({ name, estimated_diameter, close_approach_data }) => {
        const close_approaches = close_approach_data.map(
          ({ orbiting_body }) => orbiting_body
        )

        return [
          name,
          estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_min,
          estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_max,
          close_approaches
        ]
      }
    )

    const joined = this.state.data.concat(restructuredData)
    this.setState({ data: joined })
  })
```

The output is:

```
[
  [ '454266 (2014 FM7)', 0.4411182, 0.9863702813, [] ],
  [ '(1979 XB)', 0.5064714588, 1.1325046106, [ 'Earth' ] ],
  [ '(1993 BD3)', 0.0152951935, 0.0342010925, [ 'Earth', 'Mars' ] ]
]
```

However, if you're still finding that close_approach_data is sometimes undefined, just check for it beforehand like:

```
axios
  .get('https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse?api_key=DEMO_KEY')
  .then((response) => {
    const restructuredData = response.data.near_earth_objects.map(
      ({ name, estimated_diameter, close_approach_data }) => {
        const close_approaches = close_approach_data && close_approach_data.length
          ? close_approach_data.map(({ orbiting_body }) => orbiting_body)
          : [] // If the array doesn't exist, just use an empty array.

        return [
          name,
          estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_min,
          estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_max,
          close_approaches
        ]
      }
    )

    const joined = this.state.data.concat(restructuredData)
    this.setState({ data: joined })
  })
```

Comment: Thanks i just added ...close_approaches to the return and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Array.isArray(close_approach_data) && close_approach_data.length > 0` before you do anything with it?

```
const restructuredData = response.data.near_earth_objects.map(({ name, estimated_diameter, close_approach_data }) => {

    const isCloseApproachDataValid = Array.isArray(close_approach_data) && close_approach_data.length > 0

    const closeApproachesData = isCloseApproachDataValid? close_approach_data.map(data => {
        // do what you want to do here
    }) : null

    return [
      name,
      estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_min,
      estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_max,
      closeApproachesData
    ]
  }
)
```

Comment: Hi, Where should i run the check ?

Comment: I don't see `close_approach_data ` in your code, can you show me what you have done or what do you want to do with that?

Comment: @Ivar515 I've updated my answer, it can be something like that, but since I don't know what do you want to achieve I'll leave that map as blank. I also assume you will return `null` if the `close_approach_data` is invalid.